# Почему можно ссылаться на объект класса в определении класса?

Tags: c++, классы

Почему можно ссылаться на объект класса в определении класса?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass& b(MyClass& a)
    {
        return a;
    }
    int a = 1;
};
```

В этом случае мы еще не до конца определили класс, но уже можем вызвать его метод, который возвращает ссылку на экземпляр класса, почему так?

Comment: По сути идентичный вопрос: [Как ведёт себя компилятор при объявлении классов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1220386/)

Comment: Этот вопрос скорее восходит еще к `C`, когда вы в структуре `List` можете внутри объявить указатель `List* next`. Данный вопрос мне не давал покоя очень долгое время и я не находил на них внятных объяснений. Позвольте мне рассуждать на этом же примере. Если вы в объявлении данной структуры напишите `void* next` а потом просто сделаете приведение к `List*` в теле программы, то семантически это будет одно и то же, потому что любой указатель это всего лишь 32-битный адрес. А когда вы указываете имя класса или структуры, вы просто указываете как ему рассматривать данный на указываемый участок

Comment: @AyratArifullin, спасибо, а если например взять метод который возвращает не ссылку на экземпляр класса, а сам экземпляр класса?

Comment: @n1kzzz можно рассуждать точно так же. Поймите, что класс с точки зрения машины это просто последовательность байт. Вы лишь только специфицируете как рассматривать данный участок памяти, "задавая" ему некоторые рамки, а компилятор вам в этом помогает и не дает вам выйти за допустимые пределы

Comment: @AyratArifullin, извините, но я все равно не понимаю(

Comment: @n1kzzz не стесняйтесь говорить, что именно вас смущает? Поверьте, это не самая простая вещь и то, что вы думаете об этом вопросе - уже очень хорошо. Позвольте мне выразиться колхозным сленгом как принимается компилятором что возвращаемый тип функции это класс -- когда функция возвращает результат, создай в памяти (в стеке) `n-байт` с некоторым выравниваем (например, класс содержащий `char` и `int` будет не 5 байт, а 8 байт из-за выравнивания!). Вы скажете -- но откуда я знаю какое количество байт выделять в памяти, если класс еще до конца не определен?

Comment: И тут я сам боюсь налажать, но понимая, что фактический размер классу задают его поля, т.е. `int a; char b; std::string name` и т.д., то скорее всего компилятор может узнать фактический размер класса, а потом использовать эту информацию при определении функций, которые возвращают сам этот класс. Компилятор рассуждает так (наверное :)) - соберу-ка я поля у класса. Так-с, размер мне известен. А теперь перейдем к методам. Я думаю в такой последовательности точно должно происходить

Comment: @AyratArifullin, я знаю что так не нужно писать и извиняюсь перед вами за то, что вас потревожил, но спасибо большое вы очень сильно мне помогли)

Comment: @AyratArifullin и еще: вы сказали, то что размер класса задают его поля int a, char b и т. д. А разве методы, так же не задают размер? Просто насколько я знаю под функции так-же выделяется память.

Comment: Насчёт методов - они не влияют на размер и тела методов тоже не меняют размер. То, что вы объявляете их в классе - это всего лишь указание компилятору !!! с какими данными функция имеет право работать. Объявление методов в классе как бы сужает применимость этих функций в вашей программе. Если я не ошибаюсь, то адреса всех функций содержатся в некоторой общей таблице функций, в том числе там оказываются методы класса. А то - можно ли ими пользоваться или нет определяется синтаксическим анализом. Как итог - во время исполнения с т.з. программы, методы это те же самые обычные функции

Comment: @AyratArifullin, тоесть грубо говоря методы класса, это просто обычные функции, которым первым параметром передается экземпляр класса, но для удобства это сделали через операцию.

Comment: Вы правы. Примерно так и выражено обьектно-ориентированное программирование на Си. В случае с++ это также служит некоторым указанием к компилятору